# Cosine similarity matrix of linearly transformed inputs

Tags: linear, linear-algebra, cosine-similarity

Given a matrix $\mathbf{C}$ which contains pairwise cosine similarities between rows of a matrix $\mathbf{A}$, linearly transformed by matrix $\mathbf{U}$:
$$
\mathbf{C} = K(\mathbf{UA}, \mathbf{UA})
$$
is there a way of expressing matrix $\mathbf{C}$ by applying some transform to $K(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{A})$, like so:
$$
\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{V} K(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{A})
$$
And if so, what is $\mathbf{V}$ as a function of $\mathbf{U}$?

Comment: How arbitrary is $U$?  (It would be nice if it were orthogonal, for instance.)

Comment: Ideally, it's arbitrary. But if this can be made to work with some constraints then I'm also interested.